# redhat5 and l2tp client

Tags: vpn, redhat, l2tp

i am trying to setup a VPN connection with my redhat 5 machine
the VPN server I am using suggested that l2tp will work much better then my current pptp setup (which does not really usable)
any suggestions on how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

short question, no short answer possible ...

My guess is that whoever suggested L2TP was referring to IPsec+L2TP, for which there are a few tutorials out on the internet. Plain L2TP is not encrypted and hence not very 'private'. Try your luck with
  http://www.ipsec-howto.org/

HTH,

JJK